# How do we deal with revived but obsolete Facebook.StackOverflow questions?

Tags: discussion, facebook.stackoverflow

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557528/facebook-connect-permissions-error-200-using-stream-publish-with-php) seems like it's more than a little obsolete at this point, and yet today it's on my front page (as a follower of the Facebook tag). What should we do with these questions which are clearly obsolete? Pretty much anything pre-2010 is obsolete at this point, and it seems like the rush of new users to Facebook.SO is bound to revive some old threads.

Comment: Vote to close as too localised. Move on. Enjoy soft mangoes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Facebook subsite of Stack Overflow was shut down years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If it's utterly obsolete and completely unsalvageable flag it for deletion.
2. If it can be updated through editing, please edit it to make it so.

I went ahead and deleted the example you provided.

Comment: Cool. I was sort of wondering about protecting questions that maybe are too obsolete to recommend to new users but might still serve existing apps, but that's covered by editing and improving. Thanks!